# Issue in displaying selecting data

Tags: php, mysql

My issue is to display the data. It repeats the same id in it several times.

```
<?php

$check_shared_section = mysqli_query($MYSQLi,"select * from `vp_wall_post` where `type` = 'section' and `username` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($MYSQLi,$poster_username)."' ");

        $get_section = mysqli_fetch_array($check_shared_section);
        $section_post = trim(strip_tags($get_section["post"]));
        $section_page = trim(strip_tags($get_section["page_id"]));

        $section_id = trim(strip_tags($get_section["pid"]));

        echo $section_id;

 ?>
```

These are the issues that I am facing. Please help me to solve this problem.
It shows the output id

```
e4zDFOL3jBgcH8YRfkzJ 
e4zDFOL3jBgcH8YRfkzJ 
e4zDFOL3jBgcH8YRfkzJ
```

I want to show different id

```
e4zDFOL3jBgcH8YRfkzJ 
er556gdfg4asffgfgfgg
So2cLYtCTTMYD0fCNFjq
JGH63vAqIAnt5jNCH6OL
```

```
<?php

$check_shared_section = mysqli_query($MYSQLi,"select * from `vp_wall_post` where `type` = 'section' and `username` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($MYSQLi,$poster_username)."' ");

        $get_section = mysqli_fetch_array($check_shared_section);
        $section_post = trim(strip_tags($get_section["post"]));
        $section_page = trim(strip_tags($get_section["page_id"]));

        $section_id = trim(strip_tags($get_section["pid"]));

        echo $section_id;

 ?>
```

Comment: you should have a loop for the array

Comment: I tried but it was not working.

Comment: looks like you just need `foreach($get_section as $each){echo $each['pid'];}`

Comment: I'll try that one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are seeing the same `pid` value multiple times as you don't have any looping in your code at all. However the reason you are not getting all the different `pid` values is that you're not looping the results of the query. You need to use a `while` loop on the result of `mysqli_fetch_array` e.g.

```
while ($get_section = mysqli_fetch_array($check_shared_section)) {
    $section_post = trim(strip_tags($get_section["post"]));
    $section_page = trim(strip_tags($get_section["page_id"]));
    $section_id = trim(strip_tags($get_section["pid"]));
    echo $section_id;
    // do other stuff with the values
}
```

Note that if you want to further process the results outside the `while` loop, you will need to save the values into arrays e.g.

```
$section_posts = array();
$section_pages = array();
$section_ids = array();
while ($get_section = mysqli_fetch_array($check_shared_section)) {
    $section_posts[] = $section_post = trim(strip_tags($get_section["post"]));
    $section_pages[] = $section_page = trim(strip_tags($get_section["page_id"]));
    $section_ids[] = $section_id = trim(strip_tags($get_section["pid"]));
    echo $section_id;
    // do other stuff with the values
}
// you can use other loops to further process the values here
// e.g. foreach ($section_posts as $index => $section_post) {
// you can use $index to access the corresponding values from
// the $section_pages and $section_ids arrays e.g.
// $section_page = $section_pages[$index]
```